# PHP return inside object

Tags: php, return

I'm wondering why I can't return result with getData() function? it is empty in browser (PHP 7.1), I'm trying to understand why.

I can print/echo it just fine o.O

```
class testObject
{
     public $data;

     function __construct($data) 
     {
         $this->data = $data;

     }

     function showInfo() 
     {
         print_r($this->data);
     }


     function getData() 
     {
         $str = $this->data;
         return $str;
     }
}
$data = 'test';
$a = (new testObject($data))->getData();
```

Comment: You're doing something wrong because this is working fine: https://ideone.com/5V3Fgz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before $a You must write echo or print, because your method returns data, but you must tell what this data should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me just running it in [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a4a09581a3432e16027623c4df97186f91cf8ffe).

If you want to show it in the browser, put a echo or print after the $a.